# Minio server is giving 403 unauthorized when trying to do a put request on a presigned URL

Tags: amazon-s3, minio

Minio server is giving 403 unauthorized when trying to do a put request on a presigned URL.

It works in development when my front end is on local host, and the minio server is also on localhost, but it fails in production when the minio server is hosted on my server https://s3.evvrything.com

My NGINX config is

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name s3.evvrything.com;
  server_tokens off;

  location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /var/www/certbot;
  }

  location / {
    return 308 https://s3.evvrything.com$request_uri;
  }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name s3.evvrything.com;    
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/evvrything.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/evvrything.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
      proxy_pass http://nginx-s3;
    }
}
```

And then it passes proxy passes it to the minio nginx.

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    upstream minio {
        least_conn;
        server minio1:9000;
        server minio2:9000;
        server minio3:9000;
        server minio4:9000;
    }

    upstream console {
        # ip_hash;
        least_conn;
        server minio1:9001;
        server minio2:9001;
        server minio3:9001;
        server minio4:9001;
    }

    server {
        listen       9000;
        listen  [::]:9000;
        server_name nginx-s3;

        # To allow special characters in headers
        ignore_invalid_headers off;
        # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
        # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
        client_max_body_size 0;
        # To disable buffering
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_request_buffering off;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            # Default is HTTP/1, keepalive is only enabled in HTTP/1.1
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Connection "";
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;

            proxy_pass http://minio;
        }
    }

    server {
        listen       9001;
        listen  [::]:9001;
        server_name  localhost;

        # To allow special characters in headers
        ignore_invalid_headers off;
        # Allow any size file to be uploaded.
        # Set to a value such as 1000m; to restrict file size to a specific value
        client_max_body_size 0;
        # To disable buffering
        proxy_buffering off;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

            # This is necessary to pass the correct IP to be hashed
            real_ip_header X-Real-IP;

            proxy_connect_timeout 300;
            
            # To support websocket
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            
            chunked_transfer_encoding off;

            proxy_pass http://console;
        }
    }
}
```

I have double checked that the password is correct.
I dont know what else to debug, but it works locally, just not in production.
Any other information thats needed I can provide.

Comment: The answer is located here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62752413/minio-with-nginx-and-presigned-url?rq=2